# Webpack not finding images in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, vercel

I am importing some static images and I have no problems with
`npm run dev`

but when I try to use
`npm run build`
or
`next build`
it fails and I can't even deploy it to vercel

```
next info
    Operating System:
      Platform: win32
      Arch: x64
      Version: Windows 10 Home
    Binaries:
      Node: 16.14.2
      npm: N/A
      Yarn: N/A
      pnpm: N/A
    Relevant packages:        
      next: 13.1.1
      eslint-config-next: N/A 
      react: 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0
```

npm run dev/next build:

```
Failed to compile.

HookWebpackError: File E:\Github\Project\.next\static\media\IMG_1764.59cd3605.JPG does not exist.
    at makeWebpackError (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:308185)
    at E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:105236
    at eval (eval at create (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:13:28771), <anonymous>:27:1)
    at E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\webpack\bundle5.js:28:68649
    at E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:437:143
-- inner error --
Error: File E:\Github\Project\.next\static\media\IMG_1764.59cd3605.JPG does not exist.
    at Job.emitDependency (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
    at async Promise.all (index 10)
    at async Object.nodeFileTrace (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
    at async E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:136:28
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:90:9)
caused by plugins in Compilation.hooks.processAssets
Error: File E:\Github\Project\.next\static\media\IMG_1764.59cd3605.JPG does not exist.
    at Job.emitDependency (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:39473)
    at async Promise.all (index 10)
    at async Object.nodeFileTrace (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\@vercel\nft\index.js:1:35430)
    at async E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:136:28
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\trace\trace.js:79:20)
    at async TraceEntryPointsPlugin.createTraceAssets (E:\Github\Project\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\plugins\next-trace-entrypoints-plugin.js:90:9)
```

and as soon as I try to build my `npm run dev` doesn't work anymore and says

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Change the file ending from `JPG` to `jpg`.